# How to repeat animation on complete using jQuery's animate() function?

Tags: jquery

Here's my code. How to get the animation to repeat every time it completes?

```
$('img.balloon').animate({
     bottom : '100%'
}, 4000, 'linear', function() {
     // on complete repeat but how?
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function doAnim(){
    $('img.balloon').css('bottom', '-20px').animate({
         bottom : '100%'
    }, 4000, 'linear',
    doAnim);
})();
```

Comment: +1 You could eliminate the anonymous function `}, 4000, 'linear', doAnim);` but I'd imagine you'd need to reset the `bottom` to a different position in order to see the subsequent animations, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPhCa/

Comment: @patrick thanks Patrick, I was trying to figure out how to reposition the balloon after the first loop.

Comment: @Pam: You're welcome. @PaulPRO: You might consider adding the repositioning `.css()` call to your answer to cover all the bases.